# How can I manage my genealogy data on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I use several genealogy applications on Windows.

What applications for genealogy are available on Ubuntu and how would I move my current genealogy data to Ubuntu?

Comment: Where is your current data?

Comment: Frame challenge: Many good applications are available for tracking relationships and source materials...but since this question was asked in 2013, the best place for this information has changed to shared, collaborative websites. These sites are designed to share data, research notes and analysis, and DNA relationships. Most amateur genealogists that I know are slowly coming around and unpacking their voluminous files into such shared sites.

Answer (score 8):

**Native clients**

[GRAMPS](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20080403135952698/GRAMPS.html) Genealogical Research and Analysis Management Program

```
sudo apt-get install gramps
```

[image]

[LifeLines](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090824144450687/LifeLines.html)  Console based genealogy software to help with family history research

```
sudo apt-get install lifelines
```

**Web**

[PhpGedView](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090824144945115/PhpGedView.html) Web-based genealogy viewer and editor. [To download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpgedview/files/latest/download)

[image]

[GeneoTree](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/200908241451261/GeneoTree.html)  Genealogy software in PHP / MySQL. [To download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geneotree/)

[image]

[GeneWeb](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090826141442235/GeneWeb.html)   Uses very efficient techniques of relationship and consanguinity computing. [To download](http://opensource.geneanet.org/projects/geneweb/repository)

**Java**

[GenealogyJ](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20090824144533532/GenealogyJ.html)    Full-featured viewer and editor for genealogic data. [To download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/genj/files/)

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 5):

I will give you *only* a technical opinion, but you should experiment with the Ubuntu repository, it's full of nice software.

There is [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/) (`sudo apt-get install gramps` to install it from a console).

To obtain your data export it in the GEDCOM format on Windows and transfer it with any media on Linux. Import the transferred data in Linux with the `import` option.

A note: if you have a lot of data use [Lifelines](http://lifelines.sourceforge.net/) instead of [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/), because it is capable of managing a great amount of data without a great loss of performance.

Ask if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a local application? There's also https://www.wikitree.com/ for instance.